# Documents, Music, Download etc directories are read only and can not change

Tags: permissions

I am on the latest Ubuntu.  I noticed a few weeks ago that whenever I tried to download anything via Firefox it would fail.  I have just noticed in my file manager that Documents, Videos, Music, downloads, etc are all owned by me, but read only.  I have tried `chmod -R o-rwx` and opening Nautilus in a terminal with sudo and tried changing there too and those do not work either.  I just can not change them.

Any ideas, PLEASE?

Linux BaroniPC 5.15.0-40-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 15 12:54:21 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

fstab changes made a few years ago:

#/windows was on /dev/sda2 during installation

> 

#UUID=7EFBAA7D470A78F5                  /windows        ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_GB.UTF-8 0   0
#vfat    utf8,umask=007,gid=46 0       1

> 

#Downloads /dev/sdc1

UUID=29DD5A1F6EE94DBF   /home/baroni/Downloads  ntfs   auto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137 0 0

> 

#Documents sdc3

UUID=581D33AA242769BA   /home/baroni/Documents  ntfs   auto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137 0 0

> 

#Videos sdc2

UUID=7D26D47D2C4B9A2C   /home/baroni/Videos     ntfs   auto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137 0 0

> 

#Pictures sdc5

UUID=61E6CEB00317BB99   /home/baroni/Pictures       ntfs   auto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137 0 0

> 

#Music sdc6

UUID=732D95F04D5A444B   /home/baroni/Music          ntfs   auto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137 0 0

> 

#Ext_Documents Backups dev/sdd1

UUID=61000e07-7c55-4d0f-a233-c350229485ae   /media/Backup   ext4    defaults  0       0

Comment: please [edit] your question with the exact version of Ubuntu and include what, if any, changes you have made to the system

Comment: Is it a dual-boot system?  If so, try to boot to windows, then close it completely and restart in Ubuntu.

Comment: No, not dual boot.  It was, but no Windows at the moment, just the partition.

Comment: Firefox is a snap install? `chmod -R o-rwx` what is that supposed to do on an NTFS mount? Make sure you mount the ntfs as writable and make sure ntfs partiyions are not dirty and in need of a checkdisk from within windows.

Comment: Windows updates may turn fast startup back on setting hibernation flag. Then the Linux NTFS driver will only allow read only mount, so typical auto mounts that are read/write do not work. That is to prevent damage to hibernation or loss of data. Check Windows settings. More info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Dear all.  Sorry for the radio silence.  I'll have access to my PC Sunday and Monday and will take a further look then.  As for Windows.  Not the issue.  There was a Windows install, hence the entry, but that has gone since I had to rebuild some time ago and haven't had a chance to reinstall.  This all started after latest update.  I have read that Ubuntu have been changing user permissions on Home recently and think this may be the issue.  Seems loads are having problems.  Not seen a solution yet.

Comment: OK, so still not getting anywhere.

Comment: OK, so still not getting anywhere.  The "chmod -R o-rwx" is because I read that Ubuntu changed the security of HOME to prevent multiple profiles from being able to access each other's documents, etc.  This is no issue for me as I am the only user, and besides this policy makes the machine almost unusable.  It makes no difference how I look and try to change Directory access:  If I look at properties in the Bookmarks then it is root for Documents, Music, and Pictures.  Download and Videos it's me. And Download it says owner can access and create, Videos access only.  The others it's root only.

Comment: If I sudo Nautilus, then I still can not change ownership nor access rights.  CLearly the fstab is wrong, the differences between the settings shown, but that still makes no difference as in any case I have no read/write access in any cases.